# How to visualise data in a video stream?

Tags: video, streaming, visualization, http-live-streaming, bigdata

I would like to visualise data in a video stream. I can imagine doing something like creating images with the written data every second and combining them into a stream.

But I'd like to know possibilities of putting text over a video for example generated by http://logstalgia.io. Or an animated gif, other animation or webcamstream in the background.

Is there any software that currently does that or do I need to program it myself, if so, any suggestions on what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common and popular open source tool to put text over a video (or images or even combine different videos etc) is probably ffmpeg:

- https://ffmpeg.org

ffmpeg can be used in the command line or programatically as part of an application (look at the licensing carefully to make sure it meets your needs if you want to distribute etc).

To use it programatically you can either use the command line tool in a wrapper or use the libraries it is built on directly.

Using the libraries directly (libavcodec, libavutil, libavformat, libavfilter, libavdevice, libswscale and libswresample - see the about page at the link above) should be more efficient and allow greater control etc, but the wrapper approach is still popular as it can be simpler to implement at first and there is a wealth of online info on command line syntax to achieve pretty much anything you might want to do, which you get to leverage with this approach.